# An issue with interactivePopGestureRecognizer (navigation controller swipe back)

Tags: ios, xcode

my first question, please be gentle...

Swipe back from a page controller works fine if I use UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl, but not with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll. I can't see why it objects to the latter. Any ideas?

The transition style depends on the presentation mode:

```
if (inPageCurlMode) {
    // this swipes back fine
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
    initWithTransitionStyle:
       UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl  
    navigationOrientation:
       UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
    options:nil];
    }
else {
    // this won't swipe back
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
    initWithTransitionStyle:
       UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
    navigationOrientation:
       UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
    options:nil];        
    }
```

Comment: just to add, by swipe-back I mean to pop the view controller via the navigator's interactivePopGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in a UIPageViewController subclass:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for subview in self.view.subviews {

        if let scrollview = subview as? UIScrollView{

            if let gestures = scrollview.gestureRecognizers{

                for gesture in gestures {
                    gesture.require(toFail: self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that the navigationController is available, thats the reason why i put this into **viewDidAppear()**